# Calling VBScript on Windows Server from Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, email, vbscript

I have 2 servers, a Windows Server which has capabilities to send email outbound and a Linux server which does not. Because the Linux server does not have permission to send mail, but I need it to, I did the following:

I wrote a VBScript file and saved it on the Windows Server. The file sends an email based on supplied input arguments. I then mounted the folder containing this file to the Linux server.

Now I'm stuck. How can I call this VBScript file from the Linux server and have it run under the Windows Server IP so that the mail gets sent out?

Comment: I really don't know why you are asking non programming questions about Linux to Windows people. On Windows, using MS WMI - an implementation of cross platform WBEM, `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "wscript myfile.vbs"`.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to have a process that stats a file on the shared folder and operates accordingly...

You can script RDP, but it is ice-skating uphill. You can also install SSH on Windows, but you are just beating your head against the wall at that point.